# Why is Academia in Life/Arts instead of Professional?

Tags: discussion

Or at least cross-listed? It's questions are almost purely of a professional nature. It's currently grouped in with sites primarily dedicated to hobbies, or particular lifestyle choices (having kids, expatriates, etc.) and this seems...odd. The few other "profession" pages that are there, such as Writers or Video Production, are at least *arts*. Especially because it draws heavily from StackExchange, the Academia site is mostly about STEM-oriented academia.

Answer (score 2):

The categories that appear on the footer of Stack Exchange sites correspond to the [categories on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (listed on the left side of the Area 51 homepage). When a site launches, it's automatically assigned to the category that the community chose in Area 51.

For what it's worth, the "Life" category on Area 51 is defined in a way that includes education and careers, so it's not inappropriate for Academia to be listed there.

> The Life category includes proposals in subjects like home, family, education, careers, and self improvement.

[[source](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/4/life)]

Most people are probably not navigating to or discovering sites through the footer (or https://stackexchange.com/sites), anyway, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.