# Ask Patents and The Workplace are missing from the footer

Tags: bug, footer

It's quite difficult to display non-existence so this questions is, sadly, short and monochromatic :-(.

It looks as though 2 categories were added to the [all sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest), "Business" and "Professional". They each have only one graduated site, The Workplace and Ask Patents. These categories aren't in the footer, which means that the sites aren't either.

Comment: Ask Patents isn't technically graduated. But you're right about The Workplace.

Comment: @AnnaLear In many ways, Workplace and Academia are similar, but they were placed in different categories. It was [already proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228405/) to reclassify Academia as Professional; this would make the category a bit more viable in the footer. (An easier/lazier solution would be to move Workplace to Life/Arts.)

Comment: Looks like this was [meta-tag:status-completed] by https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372007/reducing-the-weight-of-our-footer.