# Move Skeptics Stack Exchange to the 'Science' section

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

As of 25 May 2015, [Skeptics Stack Exchange](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) not is inserted in the *Science* section by Stack Exchange:

[image]

While not being exactly a science site, this website exists to apply *scientific skepticism* on scientific topics, examples:

- [Has man walked on the Moon?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon/1130#1130)
- [Is the Earth 6000 years old?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old/1441#1441)
- [Do human activities contribute to climate change?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41/do-human-activities-contribute-to-climate-change/480#480)
- [Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution/2065#2065)
- [Was the experiment with five monkeys, a ladder, a banana and a water spray conducted?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-condu)
- [Does hot water freeze faster than cold water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/does-hot-water-freeze-faster-than-cold-water)
- [Do cats always land on their feet?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/do-cats-always-land-on-their-feet)
- [Are personal electronics a risk to commercial aviation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/are-personal-electronics-a-risk-to-commercial-aviation)
- [Can bullets fired into the air kill a person when they fall?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/610/can-bullets-fired-into-the-air-kill-a-person-when-they-fall)
- [Are old glass panes thicker on the bottom due to "flow"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/are-old-glass-panes-thicker-on-the-bottom-due-to-flow)
- [Did an F-15 airplane successfully land with just one wing?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/did-an-f-15-airplane-successfully-land-with-just-one-wing)
- [Will a bullet be split in half if it hits a butter knife that is fixed in place?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/will-a-bullet-be-split-in-half-if-it-hits-a-butter-knife-that-is-fixed-in-place)
- And so on..

And so on. Most of our questions involve topics including: [biology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) - [physics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) - [chemistry](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) - [zoology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology) and so on...

On this website, we strictly [practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism):

> questioning whether claims are supported by empirical research and have reproducibility, as part of a methodological norm pursuing "the extension of certified knowledge"

History of Science and Mathematics is listed in the Science section, it is not a science itself, but it is highly related to science. Same thing goes with Skeptics Stack Exchange.

Will you please move Skeptics Stack Exchange to the science section? If you reject this feature request, would you explain why *Philosophy* and *History of Science and Mathematics* quality to be added in the science section but *Skeptics* doesn't?

Comment: From the little I've seen of [skeptics.SE], no, certainly not a science site.

Comment: Are you coming to a conclusion based on little evidence you have seen from this website?

Comment: I think he's skeptical of Skeptics' scientific nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could fit in many categories at an abstract level.

Science, because it overlaps with:

- Physics
- Biology
- Chemistry
- Economics
- Philosophy
- Earth Science
- Astronomy

Life and arts, because it overlaps with:

- Health
- Life Hacks
- Personal Productivity

Culture, because it overlaps with:

- Politics
- History

Of *all* the categories where it could fit, Culture is unfortunately the least overlapping. I don't really think it makes a shred of a difference in terms of traffic, but as a matter of self-identification, yes - I think we fit better under "Science", although we don't really strictly fit anywhere.

Comment: What about having one site in several categories? Will it break anything?

Comment: @ShadowWizard They're inferred from Area 51. Not necessarily *break* per se, but I'd really rather not work around a simple system just for the sake of a "perfect" categorization.

Comment: As (almost) always @Adam, that's fair enough. :)

Answer (score 11):

I ... personally don't think the category matters that much. So, if y'all want to be in Science really badly, we can make that happen. Technically speaking, the change is trivial.

**But**, this is the sort of discussion that should be happening on the site itself first. Pitch this idea to the Skeptics community (and/or include a link to an existing recent and relevant discussion here) and we'll go from there.

Comment: [It was raised there already](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/is-skeptics-se-a-cultural-or-a-scientific-site) - which spawned this question.

Comment: @HDE226868 Awesome, thanks for the link. It doesn't look like the community was on board with the plan, although perhaps it's a bit early to tell for sure. I'd say it's disingenuous to come make a feature request on MSE to just have the change happen when the community-specific discussion wasn't overwhelmingly (or at all) in favor of it.

Comment: I agree; I was surprised to see this question on Meta, given that result.

Comment: Yeah, it could be disingenuous. But, just like design, I think categorization is set by employees and not contributing members. That's why I brought this to **meta.se**...

Comment: @georgechalhoub It is not. Communities drive categorization.

Comment: Alright; I will edit the answer on skeptics.se updating it with this post. If it receives enough upvotes I'll let you know.

Comment: It is a little premature, I've [featured] the meta,skeptics question for further voting.

Comment: There is [an even older meta post about this from me](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2270/5), you declined the category change back then ;-)

Comment: @MadScientist: I never knew Oo. Even Adam Lear edited the post...

Answer (score 7):

Let's consider what Skeptics.SE is about.  From their own [help page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.
>
> Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.
>
> If your question is not about a particular claim, **or if it is about research-level science**, the following sites may be better suited for your needs:
>
> •Biology - Stack Exchange
>
> •Philosophy - Stack Exchange
>
> •Physical Fitness - Stack Exchange
>
> •Physics - Stack Exchange

"Physical Fitness" Is a bit unusual (and probably has to do with questions concerning what the body can and cannot do), but you will note that the rest of the suggested sites are all part of the "Science" section on SE.  And, you will also find, those SE sites do not accept the types of questions you would ask on Skeptics.SE.

Skeptics.SE is about verifying those claims made outside of the scope of Scientific Skepticism, or limited Scientific Skepticism, but it is not about science specifically - plenty of the questions on the site deal with political claims, historic claims, and general conspiracy theories.  While proving or disproving these claims can be done with an approach of scientific skepticism, this does not make a discussion about such claims a science in and of itself.

Skeptics.SE currently resides in the Culture/Recreation section of SE, and while that's not a perfect fit either, the scope of questions in Skeptics.SE is too broad to justify placing it in the Science section of SE.

Comment: To be honest, most of our scientific questions also fit on the science sites. They would be answered differently (we are reference based, the other sites allow theoretical answers).

Answer (score 6):

This post may be downvoted to smithereens, but I'd like to state it for the record:

**There is no such scientific discipline as Skepticism**.

Skeptics.SE discusses **all** kinds of fringe content. It would be embarrassing to have it listed as 'science'. There are no unifying definition for the sorts of questions that pop up at Skeptics (tinfoil hattery and urban legendarium aside), no stable body of methods of investigation, and no real-life applications.

Comment: Explain why Philosophy and History of Science and Mathematics quality to be added in the science section but Skeptics doesn't.

Comment: @georgechalhoub - that's irrelevant. I do not discuss SE's decision to classify Philosophy and HSM, I can see clearly that Skeptics doesn't belong to the Science section.

Comment: @georgechalhoub - you should ask another question on Philosophy's place.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'embarrassing', I would call it inaccurate, and inaccuracy is more important than embarrassment in deciding on categorization.

Comment: By some definitions of the word (e.g., definitions 4 and 5 [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/science#Noun)), science is not about the content or the results – it’s about about the approach. You can investigate all sorts of stuff scientifically, e.g., physics, religions, politics, humans, history, the history of science, and “fringe content”, if you so wish, which is (amongst others) what Skeptics is about.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Note that 4 and 5 in your reference are "Uncountable", meaning it is an essence of science, not an object of science.  And while that doesn't invalidate the importance of skepticism, it does bring into question whether or not it should be categorized as a science itself.

Comment: @Zibbobz: Sure, but placing something in the science section does not necesarrily mean that it’s classified as *a* science, only that it’s classified as relating to science. Not everything in the business section is a business eather and not everything in the professional section is a professional. In particular, the section is called *science,* not *sciences.*

Comment: You don't even have an account on Skeptics, our site is not about tinfoil hat conspiracies. Of course we answer that kind of question, but we answer them because a significant number of people believe in all kinds of crazy stuff. We're mostly debunking all the crazy theories, and our answers are generally based on science, or on verifiable facts.

Comment: For the record, we (SE) don't spend any time thinking about categorizations. Those come from the people who propose the sites on Area 51 - the categories we use are the ones the sites were originally proposed under. (I *think* we once moved a proposal to a different category? It's rare. Point being, Area 51 rules all. Sites come in peace.)

Comment: @MadScientist: We have already a question on skeptics.se http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/is-skeptics-se-a-cultural-or-a-scientific-site

Comment: @AdamLear I wish you (SE) spent a tiny bit of time thinking of them in the context of the site footer, which at present omits all sites unlucky to have the category Business or Professional.

Comment: @yes Sounds like an oversight. Is there a bug report/feature request?

Comment: @AdamLear This one: [Ask Patents and The Workplace are missing from the footer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236748) -- the title is more narrow, but the post itself is about those two categories.

Comment: @MadScientist - not having an account does not mean I cannot read it from time to time and see for myself what it is about.

Comment: @DeerHunter true, however you could have totally avoided insulting its community by calling it "embarassing".