# Is it possible to move a site proposal to a different category?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

Let's suppose that at some point the Community of a site proposal decides it would be a better fit on a different category (if it moves from a professional to a general audience and vice versa).

Is this possible without deleting the proposal and starting from scratch altogether?

Comment: AFAIK there are no *categories* called professional or general audience on Area51 nor can I generalize the existing categories under those terms. Can you be more specific about which categories you're talking about? On a second note: shouldn't this be discussed on A51's discussion meta?

Comment: @rene Didn't know that that Meta existed. Well, there is a category called "Professionals", and a general audience would be life or another category, depending on the proposal.

Comment: Area51 meta is here: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/ and I would suggest you then mention you're asking about switching a proposal from *Professional* to *Science* or *Recreation* to have no confusion about which category you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by a Community Manager. Somebody a while ago requested that Skeptics be moved to the Science category, and Adam Lear in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257403/323179) said:

> So, if y'all want to be in Science really badly, we can make that happen. Technically speaking, the change is trivial.

Comment: Technically, that was about moving a *site* to another category.